# Can a mine get science from multiple adjacent Seowons?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

In Rise and Fall, Korea's unique Campus replacement district, the Seowon, gives science to adjacent mines.

Does this stack if a mine is adjacent to more than one Seowon?

Comment: I don't believe that this effect stacks. As it usually reads something like "+1 science to a mine if adjacent to a Seowon." instead of "+1 science for mines *per* adjacent Seowon." I'm not 100% sure of this though, hence comment instead of answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't believe that this effect stacks. As it usually reads something like "+1 science to a mine if adjacent to a Seowon." instead of "+1 science for mines per adjacent Seowon."

Shelby115's comment is correct, it does not stack:

[image: screenshot showing the mine between two Seowons only has one science]